# Categorical variables in Predictive models - Data structure question

Tags: predictive-models

I'd like to know how to best structure categorical variables.

Based on some reading I did, most researchers suggest making the categorical variable into a factor.

Let's say my categorical variables are something like

```
Variable ( no ordering here, 9999 is just missing)
1
2
3
-1
9999

Anothervariable  ( ordering here 5 is worse compared to 4 and so on )
1
2
3
4
5
```

Question
How do I structure the two variables above during data reduction?
Let's say I am using Variable clustering to reduce data. Is it better to make it a factor for variable clustering, or should I leave it alone as a numeric variable?

Comment: Is the variable categorical or ordinal?

Comment: Variable is categorical/nominal, Anothervariable is ordinal.

Comment: How are you doing the variable clustering?

Comment: Proc varclus in SAS